# HIVE RENAME COLUMN IN TABLE WITH PARTITIONS

Tags: hive

This is a table in hive with partitions

I tried:
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE COLUMN old_name  new_name
Syntax: Renaming column is not supported in Hive-style ALTER COLUMN, please run RENAME COLUMN instead

Then I tried:
ALTER TABLE tablename RENAME COLUMN old_name TO new_name
Syntax: RENAME COLUMN is only supported with v2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using wrong syntax.

if you are trying to rename a column which is not a partition column, syntax is -

```
alter table mytable change column old_name new_name datatype;
```

But if you are trying to rename a column which is a partition column, it is little difficult and you have to recreate the table with new partition column name. like below -

```
create table mytable ( col1 int, col2 string) PARTITIONED BY(new_name string);
insert into mytable partition (new_name ) select x as col1, y as col2, z as new_name from old_table;
drop table old_table;
```

Please notice the new column name in partition and then we loaded data from old table into new.